# Need advice on implementing feature regarding Django models

Tags: python, django

I need some kinds of advice. In my models I have teachers, students and courses. Each teacher has its own courses. I was wondering how can I allow students to visualize my courses, as a teacher. 
In the teacher classroom (teacher control panel), I listed his courses, and near each course I made an enroll students button. So when that is clicked on, it will redirect to the course's slug page and there he will be able to search for his students (like classroom/engineering/enroll). This is what I done so far. Now I was thinking of some kind of boolean value checkbox near each student name and when all desired students are checked, below he will have an Enroll button, which will allow those students to visualize that course page.
 My problem is, how do I implement this enroll exactly ? What is a good approach ? Please advice me.

Comment: No time for full answer now.. but what you need is a many to many field connecting students to courses.  This will result in django creating a connecting table with each row representing a student that is enrolled in a course.  Once you have that, you have to work on the UI...

Comment: @little_birdie can you point me to something similar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's not difficult what you are looking for with some investigation work. There is a lot of information everywhere about the ManyToManyField, as @little_birdie said. To learn about this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/.

By the way, what you want is to relate the course with a teacher and all the students:

```
class Teacher(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    # etc

class Student(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    age = IntegerField()
    # etc

class Course(Model):
    subject = CharField(max_length=30)
    teacher = ForeignKey(Teacher)
    students = ManyToManyField(Student)
    open = BooleanField(default=False)
```

That's what ManyToManyField does. It creates a intermediate table relating both a course and a student. If I were you, I would use a Model Form of Course model to work with the interface:

```
class CourseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = "__all__"
```

Every time a teacher needs to enroll students to a specific course, he would access to a form page. He would assign all the students he wants to the course and then would open the course so that students can see the course. After this, all you need to do is to save the form posted. And, of course, to work with proper interfaces for students and teachers.

Comment: Hi. I tried something like this actually. I posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003113/i-need-advice-on-how-to-implement-a-checkbox-in-django Please have a look.