# I need advice on how to implement a checkbox in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to create a way that a student can enroll to a teacher's course. I added a boolean field to my StudentData model and from there I added a many-to-many field to my Course model. Each of my course page is a generated slug page and there all students are listed. I want that near each student a checkbox will be shown. And if teacher selects more students and presses Enroll button, only those students can view the course.

Now, the template conditionals I can do them myself, but I am stuck on updating data the right way using the checkbox. This is the boilerplate:

```
<ul>
    {% for student in students %}
        <br>
        <br>
        {{ student.name }} {{ student.surname }}<input type='checkbox' {% ifequal value 0 %}checked{% endifequal %}> 0
        <br>
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="pagination">
            <span class="step-links">
                {% if students.has_previous %}
                    <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
                    <a href="?page={{ students.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                {% endif %}
                <span class="current">
                    {{ students.number }}
                </span>
                {% if students.has_next %}
                        <a href="?page={{ students.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                        <a href="?page={{ students.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button class="btn-success">Enroll</button>    
    </div>
</div>
```

```
class StudentDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    enrolled = forms.BooleanField()

    def __init__(self):
        if self.checked:
            self.fields['enrolled'].initial = True

    class Meta:
        model = StudentData
        fields = ('enrolled', )
```

```
class StudentData(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    student_ID = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=14)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=True)
    enrolled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    course = models.ManyToManyField('Course', default=None, blank=True)

class Course(models.Model):
    study_programme = models.ForeignKey('StudyProgramme', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ects = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)])
    description = models.TextField()
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)])
    semester = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, "1"),
                                            (2, "2"),
                                            ), default=None)
    teacher1 = models.ForeignKey('TeacherData', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None,
                                 verbose_name="Course Teacher", related_name='%(class)s_course_teacher')
    teacher2 = models.ForeignKey('TeacherData', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True,
                                 verbose_name="Seminar Teacher", related_name='%(class)s_seminar_teacher')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why 2 similar questions? [Need advice on implementing feature regarding Django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993046/need-advice-on-implementing-feature-regarding-django-models/49003783#49003783)

Personally, it's better to have the `ManyToManyField` relating course and students in the `Course` model. It's easy because, after this, all you need to do is to load the form and post it. Then:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    # all your fields
    students = models.ManyToManyField(StudentData)

class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = "__all__"
```

By default, `ManyToManyField` in forms is represented by a `SelectMultiple` widget. If you prefer checkboxes:

```
class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Course
            fields = "__all__"
            widgets = {
                'students': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
            }
```

In your template, just load the form `{{form}}` and the teacher would select with checkboxes which students are in the course. Each student will see the course by filtering using reverse `ManyToManyField` relationship:

```
student = Student.objects.get(name='John', surname='Doe')
courses = student.course_set.all() # These are all the courses where the student is enrolled
```

That's the good point of `ManyToManyField`. You can assign students from the `CourseForm` and access them from student model using reverse relationship `course_set`.

Comment: This approach I guess is also good. But this does a multiple select box. I wanted just a check box near each student name.. and how do I confirm this ? I need a button for it.

Comment: Nvm. Solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify the field explicitly inthe `ModelForm` because it is already defined in the model.

```
class StudentDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentData
        fields = ('enrolled', )
```

That's for the form definition. If you want to pass initial values then instantialize it like

```
form = StudentDataForm(initial={'enrolled': True})
```

and it will magically(not so) create the ModelForm instance with initially `enrolled` field checked.

Now in template all you have to render this form is (You must pass the form in the template render in context `context={'form': form}`)

```
...
{{ form }}
...
```

and that will render the form but if you want to render it manually, do it like this

```
...
{{ form.enrolled }}
...
```

and it will render only the checkbox. Keep in mind that you must nest it in `<form>` tags and add here a `submit` button.

more resources:

[Model Form | Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

[Providing initial values | Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values)

Comment: This is useful information, but doesn't really answer my question here..